# Wait for AFNetworking GET request

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, core-location

I am using AFNetworking to get the JSON for all of the current buses on route. What I want to do is when the user opens the view it will show all the buses as pins(for now). I parse out all the JSON and have all my vehicle objects.

The problem is that when I run the method to get the JSON it is asynchronous which means that when the line of code after the method call is ran I do not have the data yet.

In `viewDidLoad` I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self findCampus];
    _myMap.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
    model = [[ShuttleModel alloc]init];
    [model getMapVehiclePoints];

    [self placeCurrentVehicles];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Where `getMapVehiclePoints` in `model.m` is:

```
-(void)getMapVehiclePoints
{
    _vehicles = [service GetMapVehiclePoints];
}
```

In `ShuttleService.m` I have these two methods:

```
- (void)getMapVehiclePointsWithCallback:(CallbackBlock)callback {


    NSString *methodURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@GetMapVehiclePoints", BASE_URL];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:methodURL parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        if (callback) callback([self parseVehicles:(id)responseObject]);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        if (callback) callback(@[]);
    }];

}

-(NSArray *)GetMapVehiclePoints;
{

    __block NSArray *vehicles = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    [self getMapVehiclePointsWithCallback:^(NSArray *vehiclePoints) {
        vehicles = vehiclePoints;
    }];
    return vehicles;
}
```

When I get the returning array in the model to present to the view it has zero objects because the GET hasn't finished yet, how can I either load these beforehand or wait for them to load before moving on to `[self  placeCurrentVehicles]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put all the code that uses the new points into a separate method and call that from the success callback when the data arrives. You could also show an activity indicator when you make the request and hide it in this method.

You could request the data up-front, but generally you want to do as little work as you can if the user hasn't requested it.

Bus routes are unlikely to change much or often so, each time you get a response you could store it with Core Data. Now, when you need the data you can fetch it from the data store and then make a request for updated data. In this way you can show the user a route they already viewed immediately and then update for any changes a short time later. This model will also support offline display of previously viewed routes.

Comment: That was what I was going to do, however the dropping of the pins is in a view controller and the callback is in a separate class. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: You can use a delegate relationship between the class and the view controller.